# Why is the inverse fourier transform of $e^{-\omega^2+2i\omega}$ of the form $e^{(x-2)^2}$ and not of the form $e^{(x+2)^2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

So wolframalpha gives me this: [wolfram's result for inverse fourier transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcgEh.png)

but I have this relation in mind: [fourier transform rule I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BgZq.png)

and combining this with the shift theorem I would expect that 
$$f(x+a)\mapsto F(\omega)*e^{ia\omega}$$ 
not 
$$e^{-ia\omega}$$ 
which is what I think I'm getting here. I'm sure I'm wrong and I think I intuitively understand why, because of the negative sign in the function of $x$, in the exponent, but I can't analytically prove why this is the case. So far as I know, a function of the form $x^2$ would become a function of the form $(x+a)^2$, even if there's a minus sign out the front.

Comment: I edited your post to put the formulas in MathJax format. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: those constant and signs are not so interesting. so reprove the shift theorem, and you'll get your result